# test if something is a post or a taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, php

I have a custom post stored inside a `$post_or_term` variable, and I'm trying to write an IF statement that tests whether or not the variable holds a post or a taxonomy.

I have tried using `is_single()` and `is_singular()` as the test, but neither of them resolve as "true".

The code works fine if I strip away the IF statement, so that is definitely the cause of the problem... I just have no idea why.

The array below is the custom post stored inside my `$post_or_term` variable (taken from a `var_dump($post_or_term)` ):

```
array(24) { ["ID"]=> string(4) "1079" ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2018-05-14 10:41:21" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2018-05-14 10:41:21" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=> string(9) "Australia" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["ping_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(9) "australia" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2018-05-15 08:50:39" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2018-05-15 08:50:39" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> string(1) "0" ["guid"]=> string(47) "https://www.datafreedoms.com/country/australia/" ["menu_order"]=> string(1) "0" ["post_type"]=> string(7) "country" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["pod_item_id"]=> string(4) "1079" }
```

And this is my IF statement...

```
function bg_get_points ($post_or_term) {
    // Checks for a taxonomy
    if (is_tax($post_or_term)) {
        $id = $post_or_term[ 'term_id' ];
        $term_points = get_term_meta( $id, 'points', true );
        if ( ! empty($term_points) ) {
            return $term_points;
        }
    // Checks for a post
    } elseif (is_single($post_or_term)) {
        $id = $post_or_term[ 'ID' ];
        $post_points = get_post_meta( $id, 'points', true );
        if ( ! empty($post_points) ) {
            return $post_points;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: You could check either `ID` or `term_id` keys. If it's a post, then they `ID` key exists. If it's a taxonomy, then the `term_id` exists and the `ID` doesn't.

Comment: @JackJohansson How do I do that? I'm really new to PHP, just learning by examples I find on the web.

Comment: @JackJohansson Something like this? `if ($post_or_term[ 'ID' ])?`

Comment: You can use either [`array_key_exists()`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_key_exists.asp) or [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). You can find further information and examples in the above links.